How to resize Bootstrap modal width with animation
I want to resize my Bootstrap 5 modal width after clicking a button. My current code works great.
But now I want to animate this change when it's getting bigger.
I've tried with animate transition in my style-css but nothing worked out for me.
I found a lot of question regarding this topic - but none of them are working for me.
How can I achieve this? Thank you!
TEMPLATE
<template>
  <div class="modal fade modal-sm" id="modalID" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" :class="resizeModal == true ? 'size-modal' : ''">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button class="btn btn-dark col-3" @click="resizeModal = !resizeModal"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

SCRIPT
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const resizeModal = ref(false);
</script>

STYLE
<style>
.size-modal {
  --bs-modal-width: 80%;
}
</style>


A transition needs known start and end points... please provide an [mcve] .

Update your style element to apply max-width transition on your modal-dialog element.
<style>
.size-modal {
  --bs-modal-width: 80%;
}
#modalID>.modal-dialog {
  transition: max-width .5s ease-in-out;
}
</style>


It shoud be helpful if you can share a minimal and reproducible example.
But you can try the following steps first:

Update your template by adding a conditional class to your modal dialog

<template>
  <div class="modal fade" id="modalID" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" :class="{ 'size-modal': resizeModal }">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button class="btn btn-dark col-3" @click="resizeModal = !resizeModal">
            Toggle Size
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


About your script, just ensure resizeModal is a reactive varible in Vue

Add CSS for animation and handle the width transition


<style>
.modal-dialog {
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.size-modal {
  width: 80% !important; /* Adjust as needed */
}
</style>

I think this should work or at least help you.
